# Objects are not being displayed to the front end as soon as i use context_object_name in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I was trying to display a list of items on the front end of a project using Django. I successfully did it and could see the objects in a list upon spinning up the server. But as soon as I used context_object_name in the views.py file, and then check the page, the objects are not appearing. Also, there is no error shown in the terminal and the docker logs too.
Here's my Views.py file

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView
from .models import Book
# Create your views here.

class BookListView(ListView):
   model = Book
   context_object_name = 'book_list'
   template_name = 'books/book_list.html'
```

Here's the models.py file

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Book(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   author = models.CharField(max_length=200)
   price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2)

def __str__(self):
    return self.title
```

Here's the book_list.html file

```
<!--templates/books/book_list.html-->
{% extends '_base.html' %}


{% block title %}Books{% endblock title %}


{% block content %}
   {% for book in book_list %}
      <div>
        <h2><a href="">{{ object.title }}</a></h2>
      </div>
   {% endfor %}
{% endblock content %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

small mistake in book_list.html. object.title to replace book.title

```
<h2><a href="">{{ book.title }}</a></h2>
```